# How to display table data before and after filtering triggered from a click event in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, filtering, reactive-programming, dt

I am trying to create an app that loads a csv into a table and then allows filtering by specific conditions that are triggered by click events on checkboxes and a htmlwidget. I can filter by the click event but the initial dataframe is not loaded. How can I resolve this issue? A very minimal kind of example is shown below:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxInput("filter1", "A filter"),
  DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({ mtcars}) # this reads file input but I am using mtcars as substitute
  output$table <- DT::renderDT({DT::datatable(filter_1())})

  filter_1 <- reactive({
    req(input$filter1)
    # I want to load the CSV data in the table and then upon clicking on a widget or
    # checkbox only then should a given filter be applied
    if (is.null(input$filter1)) {data()} else {data() %>% filter(mpg > 25)}
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`req` checks if a value is "truthy". `filter1` is initialised with `FALSE` which is not "truthy", therefore the code for `filter_1` is not executed. Only if you tick the checkbox, its value is `TRUE` and the data is shown. This means that in the `if` clause you need to check for `TRUE`/`FALSE`, not `NULL`.

In the example, you don't need `req`. To be on the safe side, you could explicitly check if `filter1` is not `NULL` to not show weird error messages to the user during startup.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxInput("filter1", "A filter"),
  DTOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  data <- reactive({ mtcars}) # this reads file input but I am using mtcars as substitute
  output$table <- DT::renderDT({DT::datatable(filter_1())})
  
  filter_1 <- reactive({
    req(!is.null(input$filter1))
    # I want to load the CSV data in the table and then upon clicking on a widget or
    # checkbox only then should a given filter be applied
    if (input$filter1) {data() %>% filter(mpg > 25)} else {data()}
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```